# Scalatest and scalamock - dependency trouble involving SuiteMixin

Tags: scala, maven, mocking, dependency-management, scalatest

I'm trying to setup my project to use scalatest and scalamock.
I'm using scala version 2.10.0. 
However, I cant seem to get the dependencies right.

I've started with this code:

```
class  ControllerTest extends org.scalatest.FunSuite 
                      with org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory {}
```

I've tried two combinations of versions:

1)

- org.scalatest : **scalatest_2.10** : **1.9.1**
- org.scalamock: **scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10** : **3.0.1**

This is what I get:

```
scala: bad symbolic reference. 
A signature in MockFactory.class refers to type SuiteMixin in package org.scalatest which is not available. 
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MockFactory.class.
```

Note: in the [scalamock documentation](http://scalamock.org/), the artifact id is specified without the trailing _2.10, but maven couldn't find any artifact named like this. Also, I couldn't find on their site what scalatest version should be used with scalamock.

2)

1. org.scalatest : **scalatest_2.10** : **1.9.1**
2. org.scalamock: **scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10.0-RC5**: **3.0-M8**

The compiler says:

```
scala: overriding method nestedSuites in trait SuiteMixin of type => scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[org.scalatest.Suite];
method nestedSuites in trait Suite of type => List[org.scalatest.Suite] has incompatible type
class ControllerTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory {
```

and

```
scala: class ControllerTest needs to be abstract, since:
it has 5 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from class ControllerTest, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def rerunner: Option[String] = ???
  def run(testName: Option[String],args: org.scalatest.Args): org.scalatest.Status = ???
  protected def runNestedSuites(args: org.scalatest.Args): org.scalatest.Status = ???
  protected def runTest(testName: String,args: org.scalatest.Args): org.scalatest.Status = ???
  protected def runTests(testName: Option[String],args: org.scalatest.Args): org.scalatest.Status = ???
```

So, what's up with this SuiteMixin trait? 
If I use scalatest-support_2.10.0-RC5:3.0-M8, it appears to exist in **scalatest lib**. 
If I use scalatest-support_2.10:3.0.1, it seems to have gone from said scalatest lib.

What kind of sorcery is this? And, more importantly, what version combination should I use to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have this dependency

```
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

It will automatically download the correct version of scalatest. In this case it's

```
org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10;2.0.M5b!scalatest_2.10.jar
```

In most cases where one library depends upon another you just add only that one library as dependency. Sbt-like tools will get the other dependencies.

Comment: Turns out I need to attach "2_10" to said artifactId "scalamock-scalatest-support". Since I refer to classes from scalatest directly, I'm using  the scalatest version you pointed out (2.0.M5b), and it does work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

EECOLOR's answer is correct. To elaborate, the cause of the problem was that the ScalaMock version you chose was compiled against a later version of ScalaTest (2.0.M5b) than the one you were explicitly trying to use (1.9.1).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Bill. I've noticed there's no pom/sbt file in the META-INF of scalamock's jar. Is there any way to verify the versions of the dependencies other than looking at the source code?